# Sumifs not working but countifs is for same conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a sumifs function:

```
=SUMIFS(Master!DK:DK,Master!E:E,1,Master!AL:AL,Sheet1!H2,Master!N:N,Sheet1!A2)
```

that is returning 0 when it should be returning 2. 
There is one row matching that criteria, with value 2 in col DK.

I changed the sumifs to be countifs to try to figure out why it wasn't finding the 2 and it returned 1, as expected.

The countifs fx I used is:

```
=COUNTIFS(Master!E:E,1,Master!AL:AL,Sheet1!H2,Master!N:N,Sheet1!A2)
```

Any help on why sumifs isn't working as intended? I need to use sumifs and not a lookup because some rows have multiple rows in the master tab that need to be summed.

Comment: Hard to day without seeing sample data. Can you also clarify your last sentence? What does "...because some rows have multiple rows...." mean exactly?

Comment: Are any of the applicable cells formatted as text only?

Comment: Once you try `SUM(SUMIFS(,,,` an Array Formula !

Comment: I'm rolling individual data up into groups, and trying to sum values of the individual data if it meets certain criteria. Some of those groups only have 1 individual row of data that matches, and some have several, hence needing sumif and not just a lookup. 

None of the applicable cells are text only. I'm confused as to why countifs is able to get the correct answer, but sumifs isnt

Comment: Could you provide a sample, I tested SUMIFS formula it works.